Roku Media Player app shows title as "Stereo"
When converting videos using handbrake, and then playing them with Roku Media Player app, the title shows as either Stereo or Surround, even though the filename appears as the correct title of the video. Is this a Roku problem, or a Handbrake problem? And is there any fix? Thanks!
